# How do I call every piece of the api using foreach?

Tags: php, json, api

I have an issue and I thought I'd ask here after trying alone.I've been struggling to call several arrays from the api that I have to use. I'm trying with foreach but the current code displays only the last object from the api.

PHP:

```
$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.ark.bar/v1/server/209.170.149.98/16753'), true);
$name = $json_array['server']['name'];
$version = $json_array['server']['version'];
$map = $json_array['server']['map'];
$time = $json_array['server']['time'];
$playercount = $json_array['server']['playerCount'];
$maxplayers = $json_array['server']['playerMax'];
$secure =  $json_array['server']['secure'];

foreach($json_array['server']['players'] as $info) {
    $playerName = $info['name'];
    $playerScore = $info['score'];
    $playerTime = $info['time'];
    $playerHumanTime = $info['humanTime'];
}

if($json_array['secure'] = true) {
    $secureTrue = "Yes";
} else {
    $secureTrue = "No";
}
if($json_array['status'] != NULL) {
    echo "<h2>Name: $name</h2><p>Version: $version</p><p>Map: $map</p><p>Time: $time</p><p>Player Count: $playercount</p><p>Max Players: $maxplayers</p><p>Secure: $secureTrue</p>";
    echo "<h2>Players</h2><p>$playerName</p><p>$playerScore</p><p>$playerTime</p><p>$playerHumanTime</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>Server is Offline</p>";    
}
```

JSON:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "server": {
        "name": "Server Name",
        "version": 216.2,
        "map": "TheIsland",
        "time": "07:12",
        "port": 16743,
        "game": "ARK: Survival Evolved",
        "environment": "Windows",
        "secure": true,
        "playerCount": 3,
        "playerMax": 60,
        "players": [
            {
                "name": "=[A51]=Sarge",
                "score": 0,
                "time": 20520.654296875,
                "humanTime": "5 hours, 42 minutes"
            },
            {
                "name": "Tureman",
                "score": 0,
                "time": 15358.5849609375,
                "humanTime": "4 hours, 16 minutes"
            },
            {
                "name": "Borgscan",
                "score": 0,
                "time": 12156.5673828125,
                "humanTime": "3 hours, 23 minutes"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The end result is the information getting delivered to the page but the player info gets completely ignored except the last player. I've searched around how to flag them in the foreach but I can't get end results. :(

Comment: That's because each iteration of your `foreach` overwrites the last one. You have to put your `echo`s inside your `foreach` instead of assigning them to new vars.

Comment: The solution is blatantly obvious. So can we assume you are not a coder and you want us to mod a piece of code you copied from somewhere *for free* SO is not a **free coding service**

Comment: @RiggsFolly he got me fooled, thou. I used to be an expert in doing such slips.

Comment: @AlanMachado We all do it from time to time. No one is perfect

Comment: @RiggsFolly  I coded it myself but I'm an absolute beginner at PHP. I didn't use tutorials, nor other people's code just from what I remember from lessons. I still struggle in certain places. I guess asking was too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to assign  `players` to an `array`, and loop it for the output, otherwise, you'll only get the last player, i.e:

```
<?php

$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.ark.bar/v1/server/209.170.149.98/16753'), true);
$name = $json_array['server']['name'];
$version = $json_array['server']['version'];
$map = $json_array['server']['map'];
$time = $json_array['server']['time'];
$playercount = $json_array['server']['playerCount'];
$maxplayers = $json_array['server']['playerMax'];
$secure =  $json_array['server']['secure'];

foreach($json_array['server']['players'] as $info)
{
    $playerName[] .= $info['name'];
    $playerScore[] .= $info['score'];
    $playerTime[] .= $info['time'];
    $playerHumanTime[] .= $info['humanTime'];
}

if($json_array['secure'] = true) {
    $secureTrue = "Yes";
} else {
    $secureTrue = "No";
}
if($json_array['status'] != NULL) {
     echo "<h2>Name: $name</h2><p>Version: $version</p><p>Map: $map</p><p>Time: $time</p><p>Player Count: $playercount</p><p>Max Players: $maxplayers</p><p>Secure: $secureTrue</p>";
     for($i=1; $i < count($playerName); $i++){
         echo "<h2>Players</h2><p>{$playerName[$i]}</p><p>{$playerScore[$i]}</p><p>{$playerTime[$i]}</p><p>{$playerHumanTime[$i]}</p>";
     }

 } else {
     echo "<p>Server is Offline</p>";    
 }
?>
```

I've tested the code and it works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Each iteration of your `foreach` **overwrites** the last one.

As soon as `$info` gets a new array instancing, every variable that receives its fields are reassigned new fields values.

As your output lies outside your loop, it'll only write out the last value assigned to your variables.

You have to put your `echo`s inside your `foreach` instead of assigning them to new vars.

Following your code's logic, it would be something like:

```
if($json_array['status'] != NULL)
{
    echo "<h2>Name: $name</h2><p>Version: $version</p><p>Map: $map</p><p>Time: $time</p><p>Player Count: $playercount</p><p>Max Players: $maxplayers</p><p>Secure: $secureTrue</p>";
    foreach($json_array['server']['players'] as $info)
        echo "<h2>Players</h2><p>$info['name'];</p><p>$info['score'];</p><p>$info['time'];</p><p>$info['humanTime'];</p>";
}
```

*And beware your code indentation to improve it's readability.*

Comment: And please follow psr-2.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through and reassigning the variable each time so only the last one will be assigned to the variables you have. try

```
foreach($json_array['server']['players'] as $info)
                {
                $playerName = $info['name'];
                $playerScore = $info['score'];
                $playerTime = $info['time'];
                $playerHumanTime = $info['humanTime'];

                if($json_array['secure'] = true) {
                   $secureTrue = "Yes";
                } else {
                   $secureTrue = "No";
                }
                if($json_array['status'] != NULL) {
                   echo "<h2>Name: $name</h2><p>Version: $version</p><p>Map: $map</p><p>Time: $time</p><p>Player Count: $playercount</p><p>Max Players: $maxplayers</p><p>Secure: $secureTrue</p>";
                   echo "<h2>Players</h2><p>$playerName</p><p>$playerScore</p><p>$playerTime</p><p>$playerHumanTime</p>";
                } else {
                  echo "<p>Server is Offline</p>";    
                }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is rewriting a variable and then printing it after the loop is completed. Move your output code into the loop. Personally, I advocate assigning a text string to a variable and then outputting it after the loop (it's faster).

```
$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.ark.bar/v1/server/209.170.149.98/16753'), true);
$name = $json_array['server']['name'];
$version = $json_array['server']['version'];
$map = $json_array['server']['map'];
$time = $json_array['server']['time'];
$playercount = $json_array['server']['playerCount'];
$maxplayers = $json_array['server']['playerMax'];
$secure =  $json_array['server']['secure'];
$output = "<h2>Name: $name</h2><p>Version: $version</p><p>Map: $map</p><p>Time: $time</p><p>Player Count: $playercount</p><p>Max Players: $maxplayers</p><p>Secure: $secureTrue</p>";

foreach($json_array['server']['players'] as $info) {
    $playerName = $info['name'];
    $playerScore = $info['score'];
    $playerTime = $info['time'];
    $playerHumanTime = $info['humanTime'];

    $output.= "<h2>Players</h2><p>$playerName</p><p>$playerScore</p><p>$playerTime</p><p>$playerHumanTime</p>";
}

if($json_array['secure'] = true) {
    $secureTrue = "Yes";
    echo $output;
} else {
    $secureTrue = "No";
}
if($json_array['status'] != NULL) {
    echo $output;
} else {
    echo "<p>Server is Offline</p>";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chage your code like this

```
if($json_array['status'] != NULL) {
    echo "<h2>Name: $name</h2><p>Version: $version</p><p>Map: $map</p><p>Time: $time</p><p>Player Count: $playercount</p><p>Max Players: $maxplayers</p><p>Secure: $secureTrue</p>";
    echo "<h2>Players</h2>";
    $playerNum=1;
    foreach($json_array['server']['players'] as $info) {
        $playerName = $info['name'];
        $playerScore = $info['score'];
        $playerTime = $info['time'];
        $playerHumanTime = $info['humanTime'];
        echo "<h3>Player $playerNum</h3><p>$playerName</p><p>$playerScore</p><p>$playerTime</p><p>$playerHumanTime</p>";
        $playerNum++;
}
```